# Intervention analysis

Tags: regression, model, ordered-logit, measurement, intervention-analysis

I'm really struggling to figure out how to construct a model here. Basically what I'm trying to measure is if a school endorsing a statement causes that school to change their policies. I have data on school policies that are categorical with three categories - most restrictive, restrictive, and least restrictive. I have data on policies from 2013 - 2020. I also have data for each school on the year that they endorsed the statement as well as some schools in the sample that have not endorsed the statement. Basically what I want to know is if endorsing the statement makes the school relax their policies. I've tried looking into doing intervention analysis but I'm not very familiar with it and it's tough to sort out because the intervention didn't take place during the same year for each school.

Comment: You can never know if endorsing the statement caused the school to relax their policies. For the schools that changed policies and endorsed I would do some sort of fixed effects regression analysis (I think). There's a nice book by Paul Allison on these models.